# How to search a multi-dimensional array by comparing time to time range?

Tags: php, date, search, multidimensional-array, compare

```
$now   = '14:01';
$datas = [
    [
        'mk'    => 'abc',
        'timeS' => '08:00',
        'timeF' => '10:00',
    ],
    [
        'mk'    => 'def',
        'timeS' => '12:00',
        'timeF' => '14:00',
    ],
    [
        'mk'    => 'ghi',
        'timeS' => '16:00',
        'timeF' => '18:00',
    ]
];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($datas); $i++) {
    if ($datas[$i]['timeS'] < $now and $now < $datas[$i]['timeF']) {
        echo "{$datas[$i]['mk']}";
        break;
    } else {
        echo "{$datas[$i + 1]['mk']}";
        break;
    }
}
```

Because `$now = '14:01';`, I want to get `mk` value `ghi`.

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question ;)

Comment: your question is not clear at all. what you want to do? what you have tried so far? and where you stuck? what expected outcome you want from your input array?

Comment: I have changed my source code, sorry" all..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution:

```
$now   = '08:30'; $datas = [
[
    'mk'    => 'abc',
    'timeS' => '08:00',
    'timeF' => '10:00',
],
[
    'mk'    => 'def',
    'timeS' => '12:00',
    'timeF' => '14:00',
],
[
    'mk'    => 'ghi',
    'timeS' => '16:00',
    'timeF' => '18:00',
], ];
$iNow = str_replace(':' , '' , $now);
foreach($datas as $date){
    $iTimeS = str_replace(':' , '' , $date["timeS"]);
    $iTimeF = str_replace(':' , '' , $date["timeF"]);
    if($iTimeS < $iNow && $iNow < $iTimeF)
        // --> show value array 'mk'
    elseif($iTimeS > $iNow)
        // --> show value array 'mk' in next key array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more simplest solution...

Since your subarrays are ordered by their time ranges and you are rounding up to the next subarray when `$now` is greater than a given `timeF`, then `timeS` is of no consequence.

Because your values are strings with a predictable and consistent format, you don't need to remove the colons to be make an accurate comparison.

This solution shows the best-practice of `break`ing as soon as the qualifying result is determined.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Ou8tp))

```
// $now = '08:30';
// $now = '11:00';
// $now = '14:00';
$now = '14:01';
$datas=[
    ['mk'=>'abc','timeS'=>'08:00','timeF'=>'10:00'],
    ['mk'=>'def','timeS'=>'12:00','timeF'=>'14:00'],
    ['mk'=>'ghi','timeS'=>'16:00','timeF'=>'18:00']
];

foreach($datas as $row){
    if($row['timeF'] >= $now){
        echo $row['mk'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ghi
```